# Wordpress Dashboard shows no plugins installed!

Tags: plugins, errors, plugin-w3-total-cache

One of the websites that I'm working with, have some issues with designs and nothing really works they it used to. When I looked at the Plugins list, it shows there is no plugins installed. but from file manager I can see plugin folders in wp-contents/plugin folder.

It also shows the following error when I log in to wordpress dashboard:

```
W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove /home2/centralbierhaus/public_html/wp-content/advanced-cache.php. 
W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove /home2/centralbierhaus/public_html/wp-content/db.php. 
W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove /home2/centralbierhaus/public_html/wp-content/object-cache.php.
```

Any idea what is going on here!

Comment: Well have you done what the error tells you to do?

Comment: Yes, I did. it didn't fix the problem and the error stays there!

Comment: when you re-installed the pludin did it show up on the plugins list?

Comment: No, it didn't show up. None of them showed up!

Comment: What is in the wp-content folder? Are there files or only folders? Because of the error you having, it says the files are placed in the wp-content folder and not in the (child) plugin folder. If there are files, they should not be there.  The only file you should see is an index.php.